# How use multi-threading with this

Tags: php, sql, multithreading, telnet

I've been reading up on multi-threading with PHP, but I'm having a tough time integrating it into my command line php script.

I read [multithreading](https://tudorbarbu.ninja/multithreading-in-php/)
and [multithread foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125408/pthreads-php-execute-foreach-loop-in-parallel).

But I'm really not sure.  Any thoughts how to apply multi-threading here? The reason I need multi-threading here is that Telnet takes forever (see shell script).  But I can't write to my DB concurrently ($stmt2). I'm looping through my list of devices with $stmt->fetch.

Maybe I should do something like [run task specifically](https://www.sitepoint.com/parallel-programming-pthreads-php-fundamentals/), with just the telnet/shell script call in the task, like that example:

```
$task = new class extends Thread {
    private $response;

    public function run()
    {
        $content = file_get_contents("http://google.com");
        preg_match("~<title>(.+)</title>~", $content, $matches);
        $this->response = $matches[1];
    }
};

$task->start() && $task->join();

var_dump($task->response); // string(6) "Google"
```

But, I'm getting the error when I try to add this to my code below:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in /opt/IBM/custom/NAC_Dslam/calix_swVerThreaded.php on line 100
```

this is the line:

> $task = new class ...

My script looks like this:

```
$stmt =$mysqli->prepare("SELECT ip, model FROM TableD WHERE vendor = 'Calix' AND model in ('C7','E7') AND  sw_ver IS NULL LIMIT 6000"); //AND ping_reply IS NULL AND software_version IS NULL 
$stmt->bind_result($ip, $model); //list of ip's
if(!$stmt->execute())
{
    //err
}
$stmt2 = $mysqli2->prepare("UPDATE TableD SET sw_ver = ?
                            WHERE vendor = 'Calix'
                            AND ip = ? ");

$stmt2->bind_param("ss", $software, $ip);

while($stmt->fetch()) {
  //initializing var's
  if(pingAddress($ip)=="alive") { //Ones that don't ping are dead to us. 
    ///////this is the part that takes forever and should be multi-threaded/////
    //Call shell script to telnet to calix dslam and get version for that ip
    if($model == "C7"){

    $task = new class extends Thread {
        private $itsOutput;

        public function run()
        {
            exec ("./calix_C7_swVer.sh $ip", $itsOutput);//takes forever/telnet
                                                   //in shell script. Can't 
                                                   //be fixed. Each time I 
                                                   //call this script it's a 
                                                   //different ip
        }
    };
    $task->start() && $task->join();
    var_dump($task->itsOutput); //should be returned output above //takes forever to telnet
        //$output = $task->itsOutput;                                             
        $output2=array_reverse($output,true);
        if (!(preg_grep("/DENY/", $output2))){
          $found = preg_grep("/COMPLD/", $output2);
          $ind = key($found);
          $version = explode(",", $output[$ind+1]);
          if(strlen($version[3])>=1) { //if sw ver came back in an acceptable size
            $software = $version[3];
            $software = trim($software,'"'); //trim double quote (usually is there)
            print "sw ver after trim: " . $software . "\n"; 
            if(!$stmt2->execute()) { //write sw version to netcool db 
               $tempErr = "Failed to insert into dslam_elements_nac: " . $stmt2->error;
               printf($tempErr . "\n"); //show mysql execute error if exists  
               $err->logThis($tempErr);
            }
            if(!$stmtX->execute()) { //commit it
              $tempErr = "Failed to commit dslam_elements_nac: " . $stmtX->error;
              printf($tempErr . "\n");  //show mysql execute error if exists  
              $err->logThis($tempErr);
            }
          } //we got a version back
          else { //version not retrieved
              //error processing
          } //didn't get sw ver
        } //not deny
    } //c7
    else if($model == "E7") {
        exec ("./calix_E7_swVer.sh $ip", $output);
        $output2=array_reverse($output,true);
        if (!(preg_grep("/DENY/", $output2))){
          $found = preg_grep("/yes/", $output2);
          $ind = key($found);
          $version = explode("  ", $output[$ind]);
          if(strlen($version[5])>=1) { //if sw ver came back in an acceptable size
            $software = $version[5];
            print "sw ver after trim: " . $software . "\n"; 
            if(!$stmt2->execute()) { //write sw version to netcool db       
              $tempErr = "Failed to insert into dslam_elements_nac: " . $stmt2->error;
              printf($tempErr . "\n");  //show mysql execute error if exists  
              $err->logThis($tempErr);
            }
            if(!$stmtX->execute()) { //commit it
              //err processing
            }
          } //we got a version back
          else { //version not retrieved
             //handle it
          } //didn't get sw ver
      } //not deny
    } 
} //while
```

**update**
I'm trying this (pcntl_fork), but it doesn't seem to be quite what I need because when I sleep(30), which I think is similar to my shell script call, other processes don't continue and do the next one.

```
<?php

declare(ticks = 1);

$max=10;
$child=0;
$res = array("aabc", "bcd", "cde", "eft", "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj", "kkk", "lll", "mmm", "nnn", "ooo", "ppp", "qqq", "aabc", "bcd", "cde", "eft", "ggg", "hhh", "iii", "jjj", "kkk", "lll", "mmm", "nnn", "ooo", "ppp", "qqq");
function sig_handler($signo) {
  global $child;
  switch ($signo) {
   case SIGCHLD:
     //echo "SIGCHLD receivedn";
     // clean up zombies
     $pid = pcntl_waitpid(-1, $status, WNOHANG);
     $child -= 1;
    //exit;
  }
}

   pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, "sig_handler");

   //$website_scraper = new scraper();

    foreach($res as  $r){
    while ($child >= $max) {
        sleep(5); //echo " - sleep $child n";
        //pcntl_waitpid(0,$status);
   }
   $child++;
    $pid=pcntl_fork();


    if ($pid==-1) {
        die("Could not fork:n");
    }
    elseif ($pid) {
        // we're in the parent fork, dont do anything
    } 
    else {
        //example of what a child process could do:
        print "child process stuff \n";
        sleep(30);
                //$website_scraper -> scraper("http://foo.com");
        exit;
    }
    while(pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1) { //////???
        $status = pcntl_wexitstatus($status);
        echo "child $status completed \n";
    }
    print "did stuff \n";
}
?>
```

Comment: [`new class` requires PHP version 7.0 or higher.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php)

Comment: The new part is commented out anyway.  My php version is 5.3.3. The new was from the internet example I was trying to use, which doesn't seem to let me run multiple shell scripts at the same time.

Comment: @bishop - I see your comment is about my first try to use new Thread. My current thing I'm trying is pcntl_fork.

Comment: Just to be clear, `pcntl_fork` creates a new _process_ and is, therefore, not multi-_threaded_.

Comment: If pcntl_fork lets me run my shell script concurrently, and process the results together later, it's ok.  It was recommended by someone but I'm not seeing it run all concurrently, the way I have it above. Any suggestions @bishop?

Answer (score 0):

> I've been reading up on multi-threading with PHP

Don't. PHP threading has very limited utility, as it cannot be used in a web server environment. It can only be used in command-line scripts.

The author of the PHP pthreads extension [has written](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads#sapi-support):

> pthreads v3 is restricted to operating in CLI only: I have spent many years trying to explain that threads in a web server just don't make sense, after 1,111 commits to pthreads I have realised that, my advice is going unheeded.
>
> So I'm promoting the advice to hard and fast fact: you can't use pthreads safely and sensibly anywhere but CLI.

If you need to communicate with multiple network devices in parallel, consider using [`stream_select`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php) to perform asynchronous I/O, or running multiple PHP processes as part of a worker queue to manage the connections.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I can do what you're suggesting? I'm trying to use Thread, but getting an error.  See above where I'm adding what I tried.

Comment: do you  have an example for my situation? I looked at the link you gave and I'm not sure how it applies to what I'm doing.